# Socket IO connection closed Automatically

Tags: python, websocket, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I am working on a bot where we used python socket IO, am working on python automation testing where my script send messages to bot to verify bot responses are fine or not after tuning my bot always, After some time am getting following error.

**WARNING:engineio.client:WebSocket connection was closed, aborting**

For automation testing of my bot, i am keep sending messages to bot to verify responses using Excel sheet(which I prepared).
I want this bot connection to be alive to complete all my Excel rows.

Comment: Can you share the code relevant to the socketio connection?

Comment: `sio = socketio.Server(ping_timeout="60000",ping_interval="90",upgrade='false',cors_allowed_origins='*') - Creating a Server(Server)





sio = socketio.Client() - (Client)\n
sio.connect("IP Address") - This is how I connect above Server`

Comment: First of all, the timeout and interval arguments are integers, not strings. They are in seconds, and the defaults are fine for most cases. Definitely you do not want 60,000 seconds as timeout, that has nothing to do with your problem. The upgrade argument does not exist on the server, so remove it.

Comment: To troubleshoot your issue, you have to enable verbose logging in the server and the client. Add the arguments `logger=True` and `engineio_logger=True` on your `Server` and `Client` objects. Then add logs to your question.